# How to connect to a linux server only support xterm terminal

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko, xterm

I want to ssh to a server with `paramiko` modules, but when I do this, Get the server respons like:
Error:only support xterm terminal
[image]

Connect code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=blip,username=bluser,password=blpasswd)
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
```

How can I set the terminal type?
My evn:
    OS:windows 7
    IDE:pycharm
    python version:3.4

Comment: Please try to inline the server response. Makes it easier to read your question.

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` output on your client?

Comment: server response is: Error: only support xterm terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this website](http://jingege.me/2013/09/25/only-support-xterm-terminal/), you'd need to set the `TERM` environment variable to 'xterm'.

However, according to the [paramiko documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.invoke_shell), you can tell `invoke_shell` to emulate a terminal type like so:

```
ssh.invoke_shell(term='xterm')
```